# What's the meaning of these lines of code in function definitions (in tkinter app)?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

Below is all of the code. But I can't understand about two
lines of code in the function definitions,
    `pLabel.configure(image = photo)` and
    `pLabel.image = photo`. What's the meaning of these two lines? When I search it google, it says 'keep reference', but I can't fully understand 'keep reference'.

```
from tkinter import *
from time import *


fnameList = ["test1.gif", "test2.gif", "test3.gif", "test4.gif", "test5.gif",
"test6.gif", "test7.gif", "test8.gif", "test9.gif",]
photoList = [None] * 9
num = 0


def clickNext() :
    global num
    num += 1
    if num > 8 :
        num = 0
    photo = PhotoImage(file = "chapter10/gif/" + fnameList[num])
    pLabel.configure(image = photo)
    pLabel.image = photo

def clickPrev() :
    global num
    num -= 1
    if num < 0 :
        num = 8
    photo = PhotoImage(file = "chapter10/gif/" + fnameList[num])
    pLabel.configure(image = photo)
    pLabel.image = photo

window = Tk()
window.geometry("700x500")
window.title("album")

btnPrev = Button(window, text = "<< prev", command = clickPrev)
btnNext = Button(window, text = "next >>", command = clickNext)

window.bind("<Up>", clickNext)      # PageUp key click
window.bind("<Down>", clickPrev)    # PageDown key click

photo = PhotoImage(file = "chapter10/gif/" + fnameList[0])
pLabel = Label(window, image = photo)

btnPrev.place(x = 250, y = 10)
btnNext.place(x = 400, y = 10)
pLabel.place(x = 15, y = 50)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line is configuring the `Label` widget to display the `PhotoImage` object. The second line is storing a reference to this image object by explicitly adding it as an attribute named `image` to the `Label` widget. This is so the `PhotoImage` object won't automatically be garbage collected when the function returns (because `photo` is a local variable in both functions).

This is needed because the widget `configure()` method doesn't do it (as one would expect because that's how things usually work in Python — but `tkinter` is different).

Comment: Then, can I understand the second line as one of 'attach'...? 
In first line, configure (changing image).
In second line, saving (maintaing image not to disappear)
Is this right I'm saying...?

Comment: Yes, assigning it to a named attribute "attaches" it to the widget object — this is what is creating (or "keeping") the reference.

Comment: So the first line(Label.configure) is just ‘changing image’ in function. And this changed image will be disappear out of function. Therefore, we need to maintain that changed image by using label.image code. Right ?

Comment: The `configure()` method call (only) tells the `Label` widget to display the image object. The following attribute assignment prevents that image object from being deleted when the function returns — by keeping a reference to it — as would otherwise be the case.